# C# Using With Equivalent in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-translation

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://www.aaa.com");
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler){ BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{}
```

I tried to convert this code with the [Developer Fusion tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb) to VB.NET but was not successful.

```
Dim baseAddress = New Uri("http://www.aaa.com")
Dim cookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
Using handler = New HttpClientHandler() With { _
    Key .CookieContainer = cookieContainer _
}
    Using client = New HttpClient(handler) With { _
        Key .BaseAddress = baseAddress _
    }
    End Using
End Using
```

an error occured "key . "

What is the VB.NET equivalent of this code (using `with` statement)?

Comment: Try closing the gap between Key and the dot

Comment: no , i tried this before but not working...(Error 2 Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'.

Comment: ok i tried delete only "Key" word and it run!  Key .CookieContainer = cookieContainer--> .CookieContainer = cookieContainer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `Key` word

```
Using handler = New HttpClientHandler() With { _
    .CookieContainer = cookieContainer _
}
    Using client = New HttpClient(handler) With { _
        .BaseAddress = baseAddress _
    }
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

I learnt something new ([Object Initializers: Named and Anonymous Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx)) from Kilanny's answer; here's how I refactored the converted code:

```
    Dim baseAddress = New Uri("http://www.aaa.com")
    Dim cookieContainer = New Net.CookieContainer()
    Using handler As New HttpClientHandler
        With handler
            .CookieContainer = cookieContainer
            Using client As New HttpClient(handler)
                With client
                    .BaseAddress = baseAddress
                End With
            End Using
        End With
    End Using
```

1. [Object Initializers: Named and Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx)
2. [Using Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)
3. [With...End With Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)